# What is wrong withy my code Javascript? The message I get in the alert window is NaN

Tags: javascript, html

This code just does not want to work. The message I get in the alert window is NaN

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var number1 = document.numbers.nr1.value
var number2 = document.numbers.nr2.value

function add(){
var total = number1 + number2;
return total;

     }

</script>


<form action="" name="numbers">
<input type="text" name="nr1"  />
<input type="text" name="nr2" />
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(add())" />
</form>
```

Comment: Values from inputs are grabbed as strings, you need to convert to number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the numbers in your function. Otherwise it tries to get the values before anything is typed into the textfields (or even before the textfields are loaded), which of course are not defined.

```
function add(){
    var number1 = parseFloat(document.numbers.nr1.value);
    var number2 = parseFloat(document.numbers.nr2.value);
    var total = number1 + number2;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: That worked do you always need to add parseFloat() when working with numbers? What about if the user enters text? What exactly does parseFloat() do?

Comment: `parseFloat()` converts string into floating numbers (with decimal point). `parseInt()` converts string into integers.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use either **parseInt()** or **parseFloat()** then only 
string will be converted into integer because by default
textbox values are string..

your javascript code should be like this..

var number1 = parseInt(document.numbers.nr1.value)
var number2 = parseInt(document.numbers.nr2.value)

function add(){
var total = number1 + number2;
return total;

```
 }
```

or 

var number1 = parseFloat(document.numbers.nr1.value)
var number2 = parseFloat(document.numbers.nr2.value)

function add(){
var total = number1 + number2;
return total;

```
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an alert, just see the code below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){ //function to add
var number1 = document.numbers.nr1.value 
var number2 = document.numbers.nr2.value
var total = number1 + number2; //total
alert(total); //alert total
}
</script>


<form action="" name="numbers">
<input type="text" name="nr1"  />
<input type="text" name="nr2" />
<input type="submit" onclick="add()" /> <!--onclick with submit button-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function add(){
var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("nr1").value);
var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("nr2").value);


var total = number1 + number2;
return total;

     }

</script>


<form action="" name="numbers">
<input type="text" name="nr1"  id="nr1" />
<input type="text" name="nr2"  id="nr2"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(add())" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're calling the add function at that point the value is not calculated. As the two statements are present outside the function. Remember the DOM parses from top to bottom during the page load. At the page load the DOM encounters the two statements and see that they are `undefined`. So you need to move both of them inside the function. The values you get are in the form of a `string` so you need to parse them else `string concatenation` will happen.

Find below working code:

```
function add(){
var number1 = parseInt(document.numbers.nr1.value, 10);
var number2 = parseInt(document.numbers.nr2.value, 10);

var total = number1 + number2;
return total;

     }

</script>


<form action="" name="numbers">
<input type="text" name="nr1"  />
<input type="text" name="nr2" />
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(add())" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps